# Get first value of dictionary object without using loop

Tags: c#

Pretty new to C#, how do I grab this value without using the loop?

```
        foreach (var kv in error.ErrorDetails)
        {
            errorAlert.text = string.Join(", ", kv.Value.ToArray());
            break;
        }
```

Comment: There is no "first" value in a dictionary. The "first" KVP you got is just a random KVP.

Comment: all i want to do is get the first value of the first KVP in the dictionary...the order doesn't matter...

Comment: He may mean the key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Linq, `.First()` or `FirstOrDefault()` function to get first record from `KeyValuePair` irrespective of order.

```
errorAlert.text = string.Join(", ", error.ErrorDetails.First().Value.ToArray());

errorAlert.text = error.ErrorDetails == null ? "" : string.Join(", ", error.ErrorDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToArray());
```

[First() :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.first?view=netframework-4.8) Use `.First()` when you know `error.ErrorDetails` contains *atleast* one record. `.First()` will return *First* record from sequence.

[FirstOrDefault() :](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8) Use `.FirstOrDefault()`, if `error.ErrorDetails` contains *zero* or more elements. `.FirstOrDefault()` returns default value if there is no error details available.

Comment: `error.ErrorDetails.FirstOrDefault()?.Value.ToArray()` would evaluate to `null` if `error.ErrorDetails` is empty, which causes `string.Join` to throw an exception. It is safer to check whether `ErrorDetails` is empty beforehand.

Comment: Agreed with your suggestion, checking `.Count` or null check will solve this issue. Updated code to check null before `FirstOrDefault()`. I used null check intentionally if I use `Count` check then my answer will be identical to you.

Answer (score 2):

Dictionary elements are unordered, so strictly speaking, there is no "first" element in a dictionary. The supposedly-"first" object you got there could be different the next time you do this to the dictionary.

So I'll assume you just want a key value pair from the dictionary - *any* key value pair.

One way to do this is to just call `First`:

```
errorAlert.text = string.Join(", ", error.ErrorDetails.First().Value.ToArray());
```

Note that `First` will throw an exception if the dictionary is empty, you might want to check it first:

```
if (error.ErrorDetails.Count > 0) {
    errorAlert.text = string.Join(", ", error.ErrorDetails.First().Value.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
YourDictionaryObject.FirstOrDefault()
//Linq
```